# jQuery Horizontal Scroll Animation

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling

This is probably a very basic question and it's because I'm such a noob to jQuery that I don't know this.

I have a wide web site with all content laid out horizontally. Instead of using a scroll bar at the bottom I have a button on either side so that when you click it, it moves you left or right in the site.

I have the jQuery here:

```
$(".timeline_page a.flex-prev").click(function(){
$(".timeline_page_wrapper").scrollLeft(Math.max(0, $(".timeline_page_wrapper").scrollLeft() - 500));
});

$(".timeline_page a.flex-next").click(function(){
$(".timeline_page_wrapper").scrollLeft(Math.min(1200, $(".timeline_page_wrapper").scrollLeft() + 500));
});
```

So far so good. But I would like to animate it and I can't figure out how to do so. Everything I try causes it not to run.

On a related note is there a way for me to know when the user is at the end of the right or left side so I can change the button state?

EDIT:

Ok so now I've got the following code and managed to animate it. But what am I doing wrong with adding or removing a class if it reaches a certain point?

```
$(".timeline_page a.flex-prev").click(function(){
$(".timeline_page_wrapper").animate({
    scrollLeft: Math.max(0, $(".timeline_page_wrapper").scrollLeft() - 500)}, 650);
});

$(".timeline_page a.flex-next").click(function(){
$(".timeline_page_wrapper").animate({
    scrollLeft: Math.min(4080, $(".timeline_page_wrapper").scrollLeft() + 500)}, 650);
});

if ($(".timeline_page_wrapper").scrollLeft() === 0 {
    $(".timeline_page a.flex-prev").addClass("flex-disabled");
} else {
    $(".timeline_page a.flex-prev").removeClass("flex-disabled");
}
);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used it before and it works! See [demo](http://www.queness.com/resources/html/scroll/horizontal.html) and [tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery) here.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JQuery Animate() method. Try animating the position in increments of the view/page width.
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

You can tell the user is at the end by checking the scrollLeft() for timeline_page_wrapper and comparing it to the entire content width. Scrollleft should also give you the amount left to be displayed. A little arithmetic will tell you if you've come to the end of the page.
http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/

Hope this helps